# Visualise CieLAB image absent of Luminosity channel

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

Is it possible to display a 2 channel image in OpenCV (or another similar library)? I have a CieLAB image, I have removed the first (Luminosity) channel. I want to visualise this (2 channel) image now.

If its not possible any ideas how I could visualise an CieLAB image that has no Luminosity channel? Essentially I want to see if I remove this channel do I get any shadow attenuation.

```
channels = cv2.split(lab)
del channels[0]
ab = cv2.merge(channels)
cv2.imshow('ab', ab) # Error
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.hpp:253: error:(-215:Assertion failed) VScn::contains(scn) && VDcn::contains(dcn) && VDepth::contains(depth) in function 'cv::CvtHelper,struct cv::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::Set<0,5,-1>,2>::CvtHelper'

Comment: You don't get a shadow attenuation just by removing the `L` channel. You will have to use some shadow detection and removal method to perform some preprocessing on certain channels, and then put together these modified channels to form the new CIELab image. Then convert this image to RGB to visualize it.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do really, but try just using a solid grey `L` channel with value, say 128, along with the `a` and `b` channels to visualise it - it will give you an idea of the colours in the image, if not the relative brightness.